# Can i deploy .car application (synapse-mediator & REST API) on wso2dss?

Tags: java, rest, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Sorry for my English and I'm newbie in wso2. I'm using this tutorial https://youtu.be/pa-nXLaCh4I to deploy my .car application on WSO2ESB. All ok, but can I deploy this on WSO2DSS? It's doesn't work for me. Please help.

I have changed only one thing in this tutorial - export composite application project with "Server Role" = "Data Services Server". Then my wso2dss server deploy my .car app without errors, but when I use http/1.1 get request to 'http://localhost:8280/sample/log' my browser says that I can't connect. I have checked localhost 8280 port with nmap and get request that port is closed:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8280/tcp closed synapse-nhttp
```

Then I check "\wso2**esb**-4.9.0\repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml" and find element:

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener"> ...
```

which was uncommented, but in "\wso2**dss**-3.5.1\repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml" iIfound element

```
<!--transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener"> ...
```

which was commented. I uncomment this element in wso2dss axis2.xml. Then restart server, but get errors like:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` and server did not start. Then I copy 3 jars in "\wso2dss-3.5.1\repository\components\dropins":

```
httpcore-nio_4.3.3.wso2v1.jar
synapse-commons_2.1.3.wso2v11.jar
synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.3.wso2v11.jar
```

and server started and port 8280 opened:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8280/tcp open  synapse-nhttp
```

And at that moment I was stacked. I use http/1.1 get request to to 'http://localhost:8280/sample/log' but get error in browser

```
ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" 500 Internal Server Error
```

but was excepting empty page and wso2dss server console displays nothing. 
I use standart wso2dss-3.5.1 build and developer-studio-eclipse-jee-luna-win64-x86_64-3.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deploy synapse artifacts to DSS. This product is meant for a different purpose which is, working with data sources and data services.

If you want DSS and ESB functionalities together in a single product, you can install the DSS feature to ESB [[1]](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2-tutorial-adding-wso2-data-services-server-dss-as-a-feature-to-the-wso2-esb). Or you can use WSO2 EI [[2]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/WSO2+Enterprise+Integrator+Documentation) which has ESB and DSS combined together.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'll try to use WSO2EI.